# Why is my google map blank?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have not seen this before usually a map either loads or it doesnt because of some error.  I am getting the map to load without errors but it is blank:

[image]

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&#038;ver=3.0'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.9869349, -102.24306);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
  }
    </script>

 <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:300px"></div>
```

Anyone else seen this or know what might be the culprit? The map itself is sitting in a div that I am show/hide with jQuery.  Could that be the conflict?

### *ANSWER*

This was just a stupid conflict with the parent div where I had img {display:none} defined.  Oops. .thanks everyone for trying to help.

Comment: Any errors in the error console? Where are you calling `initialize()`?

Comment: no and on body... sorry for leaving that out : `<body onload="initialize()">`

Comment: Just pasted your code into a html file and the map shows up correctly for me, what is the rest of your html?

Comment: if you're using jquery you might want this plugin http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/06/a-google-maps-version-3-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

try adding this:

```
window.onload = function(evt) {
    // this is a simple replica of jQuery's ready function
    if(document.readyState === 'complete') {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.9869349, -102.24306);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont think that is it, I am loading jQuery too and I tried wrapping it in the ready function.  I also tried loading it on body `<body onload="initialize()">`

Comment: might seem stupid, but try to access to google maps manually, maybe there are some restrictions on your router, etc...

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&#038;ver=3.0'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.9869349, -102.24306);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
  }
    </script>

 <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:300px"></div>
<script>initialize();</script>
```

Comment: No I have it loading fine on other parts of the site

Answer (score 1):

I tried google's example, which looks quite similar to what you're doing, and it worked fine.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple.html

I suspected that you had the lat/lng reversed, but that doesn't appear to be the case. Perhaps work through this example again - as I just ran it locally with no trouble.

Comment: bah.. it was because I had it inside  `.thatDiv img {display: none}`